# How to wait for a process to open

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Im trying to create a function that waits for a process to open before doing other stuff with it, it  seems like it should work and im not sure why it doesnt, if it matters im on visual studio 2022 with ISO C++20 Standard and multibyte character set
(it works if the process is already open)

```
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
HANDLE openProc;
std::string choice("ac_client.exe");

DWORD getProc(std::string name)
{
    HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(pe32);
    Process32First(snap, &pe32);
    while (Process32Next(snap, &pe32))
    {
        if (!name.compare(pe32.szExeFile))
        {
            openProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
            CloseHandle(snap);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

HANDLE get(DWORD pID)
{
    bool endFunction{ false };
    HANDLE procCheck{};
    HANDLE snap(CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0));
    Process32First(snap, &pe32);
    while (Process32Next(snap, &pe32))
    {
        procCheck = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pID);
        std::cout << pe32.szExeFile << '\n';
        std::cout << choice << '\n';
        if (pe32.szExeFile == "ac_cube.exe")
        {
            if (!choice.compare(pe32.szExeFile) == 0)
            {
                std::cout << pe32.szExeFile << '\n';
                    std::cout << choice << '\n';
                    endFunction = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return procCheck;
}

int main()
{
    
    getProc(choice);

    DWORD pID = pe32.th32ProcessID;

    
    HANDLE pHandle = get(pID);
```

it does actually do the loop a few times before just seemingly giving up and going on to read a process with a completely different name, here is the last bit of the command prompt showing that it just quits for some reason (keep in mind, it prints szExeFile then the correct process name below)

```
VsDebugConsole.exe
ac_client.exe
conhost.exe
ac_client.exe
assaultCubeC.exe //this is the program im trying to fix if it matters
ac_client.exe
SearchFilterHost.exe
ac_client.exe
msvsmon.exe
ac_client.exe
SUCCESSFULLY LOADED || DETAILS BELOW

Health       -> 236
AR Ammo      -> 320 (284)
Pistol Ammo  -> 300 (264)
```

for context its supposed to read and write to the ammo and health values in a game but that doesnt matter that all works perfectly i have no issues with that, i just cant seem to figure this part out.
apologies if its something very obvious that i am not noticing lol thats happened a few times to me, but i am about to go to sleep and hopefully somebody would  be able to tell me what im doing wrong by the time im awake

i tried running with the game open which worked exactly as expected, but i just dont see what there is that im doing wrong i have no idea what i could be changing, but hopefully i will learn from this and be able to utilize this later on

Comment: The logic in your code is really strange and I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But you've written a while loop that iterates trough all the processes, but for some reason you are surprised that the loop does exactly that. What were you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: Worth saying that your code ignores the first process in each snapshot, because you call `Process32First`, ignore the result of that call and immiediately call `Process32Next`

Comment: Also worth saying that you should close handles when you are done with them, every `OpenProcess` and `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` should have a corresponding `CloseHandle`

Comment: Also worth saying that whenever Win23 API code does not work as you expect you should check the return value of every call for errors. It can easily happen that some function is erroring for some reason and you don't know about it.

Comment: I'm sure that 98% of questions with the [tag:winapi] tag could be solved simply by shipping a C++ version of the SDK where the only change is a `[[nodiscard]]` attribute on every function that returns a value.

Comment: Not sure what your intent is in acquiring the process id of the game, I can only assume it's for a game trainer. If I were you I'd look into DLL injection. It greatly simplifies the pointer arithmetic needed to get a value at a dynamically loaded address substantially when dealing with multiple levels of pointers. All you'd need to do is make the DLL and use CE to inject it into the game.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getProc()` function has several problems.

- it is not checking if `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` or `Process32First()` fail.
- it is skipping the first process reported by `Process32First()` (if it is successful).
- if `Process32Next()` returns false (either because `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` or `Process32First()` had failed, or because the end of the process list is reached without you finding a matching filename), you are leaking the `HANDLE` returned by `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` (if it was successful), and your function then exhibits *undefined behavior* by not `return`'ing any value at all, even though it is declared as returning a `DWORD`.

Aside from the missing error handling, it would be better to have `getProc()` return the opened `HANDLE` to the caller instead of assigning it to the global `openProc` variable.

You are making similar mistakes in your `get()` function, as well.

But, in addition to those problems, this statement in `get()` does not do what you think it does:

```
if (pe32.szExeFile == "ac_cube.exe")
```

You are comparing two `char[]` arrays, which is not allowed, so what really happens is that they both *decay* into `char*` pointers, and then you are comparing the pointers, which do not point at the same memory address, so the `if` statement always evaluates as `false`.  You need to compare the *content* of the arrays, not their *addresses*, such as with `strcmp()` (or equivalent).

Also, this statement looks suspiciously wrong, too:

```
if (!choice.compare(pe32.szExeFile) == 0)
```

Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), it is processed as if you had written it like this:

`if ((!choice.compare(pe32.szExeFile)) == 0)`

If the two strings compare equal, `compare()` returns `0`, which `!` turns into `true`, which does not equal `0`, so the `if` evaluates as `false`.

If the two strings compare unequal, `compare()` returns non-zero, which `!` turns into `false`, which does equal `0`, so the `if` evaluates as `true`.

So, the result is effectively the same as if you had written this:

`if (choice != pe32.szExeFile)`

With all of that said, try something more like this instead:

```
static const std::string choice = "ac_client.exe";

DWORD getProc(const std::string &name, HANDLE *hProcess = NULL)
{
    if (hProcess) *hProcess = NULL;
    DWORD pID = 0;
    HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (snap)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(pe32);
        if (Process32First(snap, &pe32))
        {
            do
            {
                if (name == pe32.szExeFile)
                {
                    if (hProcess) *hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
                    pID = pe32.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (Process32Next(snap, &pe32));
        }
        CloseHandle(snap);
    }
    return pID;
}

HANDLE get(DWORD pID)
{
    HANDLE procCheck = NULL;
    HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (snap)
    {
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(pe32);
        if (Process32First(snap, &pe32))
        {
            do
            {
                procCheck = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
                std::cout << pe32.szExeFile << '\n';
                std::cout << choice << '\n';
                if (strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, "ac_cube.exe") == 0)
                {
                    if (choice != pe32.szExeFile)
                    {
                        std::cout << pe32.szExeFile << '\n';
                        std::cout << choice << '\n';
                        break;
                    }
                }
                CloseHandle(procCheck);
                procCheck = NULL;
            }
            while (Process32Next(snap, &pe32));
        }
        CloseHandle(snap);
    }
    return procCheck;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE openProc;
    DWORD pID = getProc(choice, &openProc);
    if (pID != 0)
    {
        HANDLE pHandle = get(pID);
        if (pHandle)
        {
            ... 
            CloseHandle(pHandle);
        }
        if (openProc) CloseHandle(openProc);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, I honestly do not understand what you are trying to accomplish with the `get()` function.  If all you are trying to do is wait for a process to start running, your `getProc()` function will suffice, eg:

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE pHandle;
    DWORD pID;
    while ((pID = getProc(choice, &pHandle)) == 0) {
        Sleep(10);
    }

    // use pID and pHandle as needed...

    CloseHandle(pHandle);
    
    return 0;
}
```